# Homebrew error when installing php in Mac

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I am trying to insall php with homebrew, but after downloading some files the installation returns the error:

`Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/javier/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/784f6ce1c9212ab1acb859b2b1900ce46010c258b0c33be68c5e2f784fc7a1dc--brotli--1.1.0.arm64_ventura.bottle.1.tar.gz`

I have a MacBook Pro with the M1 Pro chip.

I am trying to install it with `brew install php`. `brew doctor` returns ready to brew with no errors. Tried uninstalling but there is no keg `Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php`.

Edit: Looks like I was having a problem updating my homebrew. Previously, when I tried `brew update`, it said that my homebrew was up to date. Today, the I tried updating it another time and then `brew upgrade`, tested `brew install php` and it worked.

Comment: I just ran into this too.  I'm compiling from source which you can too if it's an emergency. Download from source https://www.php.net/downloads.php then `brew install pkg-config libiconv` then `./configure  --with-iconv=$(brew --prefix libiconv)` then `make -j4`.  You could then `sudo make install` at the end too.  I'm hoping it's just a bug with the brew formula and they'll fix it eventually.

Comment: I installed php on my Mac M1 using https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php. See if this helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked wonders with `brew upgrade` and then `brew install php`.

Comment: For me it was just to `brew upgrade`, no need for installing php

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I install `brotli` first. Write:

`brew install brotli`

Then it works for php installation.

Comment: need brew reinstall libunistring before brew install php@8.1 in my case, otherwise it will has error:
dyld[82361]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libunistring/lib/libunistring.2.dylib